# Why does ARCamera of Vuforia look like this in Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I made an android AR app with Vuforia in Unity3D. Why it looks like this when run in Android smartphone, it works well in Unity3D, and I think it's the problem of ARCarema, because it looks the same when I only add an ARCamera to the scene.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: May be your model's is not well positioned on target image.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I've solved this problem by upgrading Unity to the newest version, so maybe it's a bug of Unity in that version.